# Function space and its relation with vectors in $\mathbf{R}^{n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality

I'm studying *Linear algebra, by Gilbert Strang*  and was going through a chapter on orthogonality.

The vectors I've dealt with are a set of numbers and I understand the inner product (defined as $a^Tb$), orthogonality ,projection of vectors onto other vectors, onto a space  spanned by such vectors and Gram Schmidt orthogonalisation process.

However at the end the author in brief discusses functional spaces ,in which the above mentioned vectors are replaced by functions. He defines the inner product of these vectors  as an definite integral,and from it follows the definition of orthogonality.

The author without giving a proof, uses all the results developed for the cases in which vectors were a set of numbers.
He does Gram Schmidt process, least squares and all by conveniently changing the definition of few things without saying why it should be true. As an example he does this:

The author tries to find the best fitting parabola using vectors ($1,x^2$) to $f(x)$ and uses the normal equation derived earlier for $\mathbf{R}^{n}$ which is
$$A^{\mathrm{T}} A \widehat{x}=A^{\mathrm{T}} b$$

In this function space he writes

$A^{\top} A=\left[\begin{array}{lll}(1,1) & (1, x) & \left(1, x^{2}\right) \\ (x, 1) & (x, x) & \left(x, x^{2}\right) \\ \left(x^{2}, 1\right) & \left(x^{2}, x\right) & \left(x^{2}, x^{2}\right)\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{lll}\int 1 & \int x & \int x^{2} \\ \int x & \int x^{2} & \int x^{3} \\ \int x^{2} & \int x^{3} & \int x^{4}\end{array}\right]$

How do I know this works for this case?
Although I see a strong analogy in both the cases but I don't understand why exactly the second case follows from the first.

Is it that the functional space  linear algebra can be deduced from the former case, and the author assumes that the student will provide the proofs?

Comment: Without specific example, it is hard to give a very precise answer. The general idea is that the proofs which work on $\mathbb R^n$, but use only the algebraic properties of the scalar product can be generalized to any vector space equipped with a scalar product, and in particular function spaces.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'll add an example.

Comment: A function can be considered an uncountable tuple of real numbers. E.g. $(f(x))_{x \in X}$

Comment: As SolubleFish already says, most of the things you mentioned (for example Gram-Schmidt) only rely on the existence of a scalar product, that is a bilinear symmetric, positive definite map from $V^2$ to $K$ where $V$ is the vector space and $K$ the field. And for orthogonality, the definition is that two elements (often called vectors) are orthogonal iff their scalar product is zero, so that also works with any scalar product.

Comment: @Lukas, till now the author has not discussed anything about bilinear, positive definite .

Comment: @Kashmiri that is not good for my comment... But then I can just say: In any vector space equipped with an inner product/scalar product we can talk about orthogonal vectors, about Gram Schmidt and so on...
A scalar product/inner product is a way more general concept than the definition $v^Tw$ that we know from $\mathbb R^n$, for more information see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Definition

Comment: I'll add an example to elucidate my question. Thank you for your response :)

Comment: @rubikscube, thank you. I agree but then other definitions need to be modified such as the inner product, norm etc which casts doubts.

Comment: @Solublefish, please see it now

Comment: @Lukas I think you meant to say that they are orthogonal if their INNER product is 0, not scalar (as that wouldn't even make sense)

Comment: @Kashmiri The inner product for vectors in $n$ dimensional space is $\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_iy_i$. We can do something similar for functions $f,g$ and write the inner product as $\sum_{x \in X} f(x)g(x) \approx \int_X f(x)g(x)\mathrm{d}x$. Note that the approximate equals here doesn't mean much - the sum on the left hand side isnt actually equal to the integral, but it's a way to interpret the integral as a """uncountable sum""" (big air quotations).

Comment: I agree with the strong analogies between the two cases but still doesn't it need a proof ? I'm not sure is the author just introducing these topics and hence no proof or he is serious and thinks the student will do it on his own?!

Comment: Possibly, because the author thinks the amount of technical machinery required for the proofs (it can be substantial - see my answer below) outweighs the pedagogical benefit of presenting the results in full rigor.  To quote Terry Tao, the purpose of rigor is to reinforce good intuition and eliminate bad intuition - here, the intuition is fairly obvious and the rigor really doesn't improve it very much, so it's totally justified to omit it.

Answer (score 1):

Almost.  A lot of results carry over exactly - a lot of other results carry over *almost* exactly, but differ in important technical details.  There are conceptual subtleties that make the infinite-dimensional case a bit frustrating.

For example: The inner product has to be defined for any two functions in a function space - in practice, this rules out a lot of functions that we might, in principle, be interested in.  For example, the Hilbert space $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ does not include the sinusoids $x \to e^{ikx}$.

In a finite-dimensional vector space, any self-adjoint linear operator has an orthonormal eigenbasis, and can be diagonalized in terms of this basis.  In the infinite-dimensional case, this becomes more difficult, because as we see above (recall that sinusoids are eigenfunctions of the imaginary differential operator $f \to -i\frac{df}{dx}$), our eigenfunctions may not *strictly* lie in our function space.

There are a number of ways of dealing with this (for example, the [Gelfand triple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigged_Hilbert_space)), none of which are particularly pretty - but the underlying intuition is pretty simple in all of them, and the difficulty is chiefly technical.

Comment: An additional fact not worthy of a separate answer: One of the interesting things when you get to functional spaces is that the integral is continuous but the derivative is not, so any differential equation that can be re-written in terms of integrals tends to get done that way.